# pi zero wifi via SD card connected to usb pins

Tags: wifi, usb, sd-card, pi-zero

I have a safecom SDW11B WLAN SD card, and recently baught a raspberry pi zero to exerement with.
I've seen some cool tutorials on how people have used a stripped usb wifi card soldered to the usb to create a low profile wifi capability.
Given there is some compatibility with SD and wifi connections, would it be possible to do the same with my sd card? has anyone done this before?

If the answer is buy a usb wifi adaptor, thats fine, but I already own a very thin sd wifi adaptor which is not in use, so if i can use it via usb that would be cool.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This is *extremely* unlikely to work.

The [latest drivers](http://www.driverguide.com/driver/detail.php?driverid=873020) for that card (that I can find) are from 2005, and are for the following versions of Windows only:

> Windows 2003, Windows XP, Windows 2000, Windows NT4, Windows NT3.51,
>   Windows ME, Windows 98SE, Windows 98, PDA

You need Linux/ARM or Windows IoT/ARM drivers in order to make anything work with a Pi. Maybe your Google Fu is stronger than mine and there are some out there somewhere, but the card predates the Pi by at least 7 years. It seems deeply unlikely that anyone would take the time to create drivers for such a niche item.

Comment: OK, thanks for the response, it was worth a try. I've spent some time on-line digging without much luck. I had found an article where someone had done a similar thing with a wifi sd card through the IO header, but have yet to find the article again, and it was more than likely a different card. I think my most likely action would be to purchase the common raspberry pi usb wifi dongle.